# Apache Shiro. What is the difference between WebUtils.isWeb(...) and WebUtils.isHttp(...)?

Tags: java, shiro

I'm just curious what is the conceptual difference between two almost identical methods `isWeb` and `isHttp` in `org.apache.shiro.web.utils.WebUtils` class and how their behavior differs from each other?

```java
public static boolean isWeb(Object requestPairSource) {
    return requestPairSource instanceof RequestPairSource
            && isWeb((RequestPairSource) requestPairSource);
}

public static boolean isHttp(Object requestPairSource) {
    return requestPairSource instanceof RequestPairSource
            && isHttp((RequestPairSource) requestPairSource);
}

private static boolean isWeb(RequestPairSource source) {
    ServletRequest request = source.getServletRequest();
    ServletResponse response = source.getServletResponse();
    return request != null && response != null;
}

private static boolean isHttp(RequestPairSource source) {
    ServletRequest request = source.getServletRequest();
    ServletResponse response = source.getServletResponse();
    return request instanceof HttpServletRequest
            && response instanceof HttpServletResponse;
}
```

P.S. This is Shiro and Java related question as I'm newbie to both.

Comment: Difference is that isHttp checks that request and response instance of  HttpServletRequest and HttpServletResponse, not just ServletRequest or ServletResponse and that request/response can provide you HTTP info like headers, methods etc. Both are interfaces and inplementation depends on vendor container/app server

Comment: Thanks @GeorgyGobozov, now I see that isHttp is more specific than isWeb.

Comment: Mark my answer as accepted to make your question answered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Difference is that isHttp checks that request and response instance of HttpServletRequest and HttpServletResponse, not just ServletRequest or ServletResponse and that request/response can provide you HTTP info like headers, methods etc. Both are interfaces and inplementation depends on vendor container/app server

Comment: Thanks to @GeorgyGobozov I've got that `WebUtils.isWeb(...)` is generic, protocol-independent check, while `WebUtils.isHttp(...)` is HTTP-specific check.

P.S. I could know it if I read about Servlet API and this trivial question wouldn't come up. Now I'm going to fill this gap ;-)